# VS 2010 and SFML : Access Violation Issue on window.display()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfml

I have recently started using SFML on Visual c++ 2010. I have linked all of the libraries and included all of the required files but still when I run my "main.cpp" the compiler throws an Unhandled Exception i.e.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in SFML.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

My program:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        //window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the crash *always* happen, or only when you close the window?

Comment: Do you have library .dll's in the right place so your .exe can access them? I had similar looking error when working in opencv and dll's were missing.

Comment: Yes the crash is always happening.Same code works fine in my office machine.But in my home laptop this weird issue occurs. The surprising thing is that same issue occurs also when i try to run the same program in office machine remotely. What am i missing?

Comment: I have placed all the necessary dlls in the .exe folder.

Comment: You sure you didn't mix debug/release librairies? I've seen that happening when mixed.

Comment: No i have not mixed debug/release libs.

Comment: Hello Guys, i resolved it.It was related to Open GL setting.Even i am not able use shaders in my program as my graphics don't support directx. need to upgrade it.